# php mysql select set of columns from table one based on values of colons in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. 
Table1:

```
deviceID    | PartA-present | PartB-present
------------+---------------+---------------
123         | 0             | 1
254         | 1             | 0
152         | 1             | 1

Table 2: 
deviceID    | PartA-Data    | PartB-Data
------------+---------------+---------------
123         | 0             | 13
152         | 4             | 25
123         | 0             | 67
152         | 38            | 32
```

Now, the presence of partA, partB, etc are dynamic based on user settings. How can I form a query to export only those columns from table2 for which the parts are present (As indicated in table 1)?

In this case, for deviceID=123, I need to export only partB-Data from table 2

**EDIT**

Based on the answers I got, I think I should clarify. I have some idea of JOIN, but I cannot figure out how to get the following result.

Desired Result (for deviceID123):

```
deviceID    | PartB-Data    | 
------------+---------------+
123         | 13            | 
123         | 67            |
```

Desired Result (for deviceID 152):

```
 deviceID   | PartA-Data    | PartB-Data
------------+---------------+---------------
152         | 4             | 25
152         | 38            | 32
```

**UPDATE**

What I was looking for was to get different number of columns in the output based on query, but thanks to @Alex, I realized it is not possible. In that sense, I can simply export table 2 for deviceID=xxx bcz the non relevant data is 0 anyways.

Comment: is the presence of part A/B column is like a bit ?  only 0/1 can be there ?

Comment: @farhangdon yes it is always 0/1

Comment: even with your edit it is not clear what should be in result when table2 has record :`152,13,54` for example?

Comment: @Alex I show two desired result examples, to show different cases.

Comment: you can't show different number of columns using the same query using mysql! if you want to return 3 columns - that is 1 query, if you want to return 2 columns that is another query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is not clear. But just as a start point try this fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bb4d/1

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.deviceid = t2.deviceid
WHERE t1.deviceID = 123
AND (t1.partA OR t2.partB)
```

**EDIT 1** it is not about your table1 fields, it is about logic

check this fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7984/5

and this query

```
SELECT t1.deviceid,
    IF(t1.partA=1, t2.partA, IF(t1.partB=1,t2.partB,null))
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.deviceid = t2.deviceid
WHERE t1.deviceID = 123
AND (t1.partA OR t2.partB);
```

even if it brings expected result for deviceid=123, does it still work for deviceid=152?

**EDIT 2** Hope I get your goal correctly. Check new fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7984/7

```
SELECT t1.deviceID,
  IF(t1.partA=1, t2.partA, null),
  IF(t1.partB=1, t2.partB, null)
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.deviceid = t2.deviceid
WHERE t1.deviceID = 123
AND (t1.partA OR t2.partB);
```

Comment: I do have an idea for JOIN, but the problem is, I dont want PartA-Data table to show because partA-present is 0.

Comment: But do you know how result table must looks like for the deviceid=152? just show me data sample and expected result for the record like deviceid=152 where both values are **1**

Comment: He doesn't need table 1 data selected.

Comment: @Alex yes, I believe you got my goal. Is there a way to NOT HAVE that null column in the result? ie, show only columns in result if table1 value is 1?

Comment: NO! you can't get different number of columns using the same query! according to your post you expect to have 2 columns if only partA or partB set to 1, but 3 columns if both are **1** that is impossible.

Comment: @Alex, ok then your solution is what I need. I thought I could get variable number of columns based on query. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT table2.*, table1.* 
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.deviceID = table2.deviceID
WHERE table2.deviceID = 123
AND (table1.PartA-present = 1 OR table1.PartB-present = 1)
```

This will join the two tables together and will only return rows when the a is present.

You should select all entries in table 2 where one of the parts is present and then just check using php

```
if ($row['PartA-present'] == 1) {
    echo $row['PartA-Data']; 
}
```

It might make more sense to simply make your table look like this though:

```
Table 2: 
deviceID    | PartA-Data    | PartB-Data
------------+---------------+---------------
123         | -1             | 13
123         | -1             | 25
```

A -1 indicates the part isn't present. That way your queries will be faster and simpler because you'll be eliminating the join which adds time and complexity to the query.

Comment: I do have an idea for JOIN, but the problem is, I dont want PartA-Data table to show because partA-present is 0. With your query, both partA-Data and partB-data are showing.

Comment: What do you mean showing? You don't have to 'show' them to the user - you can use php to check if the value is not -1 and show it if it's not

Comment: yes I have to, bcz I am working on an export Data feature. So I only want to export the rows where parts are present

Comment: No, I want columns from table2 for only what is "1" in table 1. And this changes based on user prefs

Comment: Like I said though, it'd make a lot more sense to change your database format - Joins make your query much slower.